# Can I replace a md5 signed SSL/TLS Root Certificate with a sha1 or 256 without re-signing the intermediate / end certificate?

Tags: ssl-certificate, md5, sign, sha, thawte

I have an SSL / TSL certificate which is signed with sha1. However, the root certificate from thwatke is signed with the old and vulnerable md5 algorithm. After updating an enterprise application, I got an error because the root certificate using md5.

Now I have to replace the root certificate with a sha1 or sha256 (which is newer and safer) that the applications run again.

Is it possible to just replace thwatke's root certificate with a version which is signed by sha1 or do I need to recreate the whole chain? Can thwatke do this for me? I bought the certificate just some months ago...

Answer (score 0):

To verify a signature of a certificate the public key of the issue as used. As long as this key is the same it does not matter which signature algorithm is used for the issuer certificate. It is not uncommon for CA to have the same public key in a certificate for different certificates signed with different signature algorithms. But since it is unknown about which specific certificates you are talking you have to check yourself if these have the same public key.

> After updating an enterprise application, I got an error because the root certificate using md5.

That's strange or an error in the application. A root certificate is trusted because it is in the trust store and not because of its signature. Thus the signature algorithm should not matter at all since the signature of a root certificate does not need to be verified.